# remove $ from dataLayer total - google tag manager

Tags: javascript

I have this datalayer on my completion checkout page. everything is working it fires fine. All is well for Adwords. however another ad words tracking script isn't passing the value back to the website. I believe it's because the $ sign. how can i trim the dollar sign off of the summary.total_formatted?

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({'subtotal':'<%= summary.total_formatted %>'});
</script>
```

I was thinking something like this here,

```
dataLayer.push({'subtotal':'<%= summary.total_formatted %>'[0].innerHTML.trim().replace('$','')});
```

but this is wrong gives me an arrow with the trim actually. what is the best way to handle this so the price is pasted back to the 3rd party website. I just want to exclude the $ sign to test this.

Comment: You cannot perform a replace on 'summary.total_formatted' before bind it?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it directly 
    var subTotal = '<%= summary.total_formatted %>';
    var dataLayer = [];
    dataLayer.push({'subtotal' : subTotal .replace('$','')});

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataLayer));
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/5o2h145v/1/)

Hope this helps.